# Kafka MirorMaker2 ports for inter cluster communication

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-mirrormaker

I have setup Apache MirrorMaker 3.0.0 with active-active strategy for two Kafka clusters (named DC, DR). So topic on DC is replicated by MirrorMaker2 as DC.<topic_name> on the DR cluster and vice-vera.

In each cluster i have setup 3 kafka broker nodes.

Lets suppose below IP config is used

```
DC 1st node IP : kafka-dc-server1:9092
DC 2nd node IP : kafka-dc-server2:9092
DC 3rd node IP : kafka-dc-server3:9092

DR 1st node IP : kafka-dr-server1:9092
DR 2nd node IP : kafka-dr-server2:9092
DR 3rd node IP : kafka-dr-server3:9092
```

Connect-maker properties

```
DC.bootstrap.servers = kafka-dc-server1:9092, kafka-dc-server2:9092, kafka-dc-server3:9092
DR.bootstrap.servers = kafka-dr-server1:9092, kafka-dr-server2:9092, kafka-dr-server3:9092
```

Just want to understand whether only 9092 port is sufficient to inter cluster communication(records, offset and other metadata transition) or do we need to open connectivity on some ports also?

Answer (score 0):

If port `9092` is used as each `server.properties` > `listeners` setting, then , yes, those are the bootstrap-server values for any client communication.

Comment: Bidirectional connectivity on port 9092 is opened, still we are getting error : [2022-05-18 12:07:32,426] ERROR [MirrorSourceConnector|worker] Scheduler for MirrorSourceConnector caught exception in scheduled task: syncing topic ACLs (org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.Scheduler:102)

java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SecurityDisabledException: No Authorizer is configured on the broker

Comment: Error seems self explanatory if you're not using plaintext connection and require an authorizer to be configured. But that's not related to your question about needing different ports